# Where is the Microsoft Connect entry for SELECT-EXEC?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

Can anyone point me to the Connect suggention entry for the `SELECT-EXEC` bug, so i may upvote it?

---

It's been 10 years, and i'm still cursing SQL Server for not allowing `SELECT-EXEC` syntax, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   EXECUTE GetKnownTerroristList @StartDate='2010-01-01', @EndDate='2010-11-01'
)
```

or

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetTransactionsByLCT @LCTGUID uniqueidentifier AS

   SELECT * FROM Transactions
   WHERE LCTGUID = @LCTGUID

   UNION ALL

   EXECUTE DATACENTER.Accounts.dbo.GetTransactionsByLCT @LCTGUID = @LCTGUID
```

or

### Example 3 - The real-world problem

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetTransactionsByLCT @LCTGUID uniqueidentifier AS

   EXECUTE GetTranasctionsByLCT_90 @LCTGUID = @LCTGUID

   UNION ALL

   EXECUTE DATACENTER.Accounts.dbo.GetTransactionsByLCT @LCTGUID = @LCTGUID
```

[Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/) has [a well-known page of suggested alternatives](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html); but none of them are proper workarounds (i.e. they cannot replicate the desired functionality).

i know there **must** be a [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com) entry dedicated to this issue; since thousands of people have run into it. But [my searches of Connect come up empty](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=select%2bexec).

Can anyone point me to the Connect suggention entry for the `SELECT-EXEC` bug, so i may upvote it?

---

Edit: Summary of Erland's workaround:

- [Using OUTPUT Parameters](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#OUTPUT) - Not generally applicable, but sometimes overlooked.
- [Table-valued Functions](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#UDF) - Probably the best method for output, but has some restrictions.
- [Using a Table](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#usingtable) - Most general methods with no restrictions, but a little more complex to use.
- [INSERT-EXEC](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#INSERTEXEC) - Does not require rewrite. Has some gotchas.
- [Table Parameters and Table Types](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#tableparam) - Could have been the final answer, but due to a restriction it is only mildly useful in this context. (SQL 2008)
- [Using the CLR](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#CLR) - Does not require a rewrite. Clunky, but is useful as a last resort when INSERT-EXEC does not work. (SQL 2005)
- [OPENQUERY](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#OPENQUERY) - Does not require rewrite. Tricky with many pitfalls.
- [Using XML](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#XML) - A roundabout way that requires you to make a rewrite, but it has some advantages over the other methods. (SQL 2005)
- [Using Cursor Variables](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html#cursor) - Not recommendable.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's by design. If there was an MS Connect item raised by someone, I'm pretty sure it would have closed as "By Design".

Comment: how do you expect to handle multiple returned result sets that you can return from a stored procedure? as AdaTheDev says this is by design.

Comment: @Mladen Prajdic: There isn't multiple returned results sets.

Comment: @Mladen Prajdic: Pretend i wanted to do `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = (SELECT UserID FROM Employees WHERE EmployeeName = 'Ian')`  You might say, "How do you expect to handle multiple rows returned from `Employees`?" There **aren't** multiple rows returned. And *even* if there was: SQL Server can throw an error (e.g. "Subquery returned more than 1 value."). No reason to take away the feature because it can be used wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/257882/use-of-stored-procedures-with-select) is the closest one I could find.

Comment: Accepted. i'm surprised there's not more attention on it, considering there's 5 duplicated questions on SO, thousands more hits on google, and a well-referenced page of workarounds by an well-known SQL Server MVP.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Table-Valued Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx) instead?

Comment: You have to declare the table. When the number, or type, of columns from the stored procedure change: the solution breaks.